# Two header button left and right React Navigation v5

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-vector-icons

Im trying to achieve this

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVLt9.png)

`headerRight` doesn't work, only `headerLeft` and `headerTitle` working

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

    <HomeStack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{headerStyle: {elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0}}}>
          <HomeStack.Screen
            name={NAVIGATOR.ProviderTypeTab}
            component={ProviderTypeStack}
            options={{
              title: null,
              headerLeft: () => (
                <View style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 10}}>
                  <ProfilePicComponent onPress={handleDrawer} />
                </View>
              ),
              headerRight: () => {
                <View style={{height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                  {/* <Icon name="location-on" size={24} /> */} //headerRight doesn't work
                </View>;
              },

              headerTitle: () => (
                <View style={{width: '85%', marginTop: 10}}>
                  <SearchInputComponent onPress={handleDrawer} />
                </View>
              ),
            }}
          />
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

headerRight is same as headerLeft but you are not returning anything from the function that you have provided for headerRight

Change

```
headerRight: () => {
                <View style={{height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                  {/* <Icon name="location-on" size={24} /> */} //headerRight doesn't work
                </View>;
              },
```

To

```
headerRight: () => (
                <View style={{height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                  {/* <Icon name="location-on" size={24} /> */} //headerRight doesn't work
                </View>;
              ),
```

Or

```
headerRight: () => {
               return  (<View style={{height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                  {/* <Icon name="location-on" size={24} /> */} //headerRight doesn't work
                </View>);
              },
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much. Im just confused on `headerLeft`, im not returning anything but still it renders.

Comment: It is returning, basically its an arrow function and if you use curly braces you have to return something from the function and if you put brackets, the value inside the bracket would be the return value